# Excel charts are placed on different positions depending on screen resolution

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating some charts with VBA. Target is to position them at the upper left corner of a cell (here as range rgCht) with a size of 16 rows x 9 columns.

Here is the code:

```
    ' Calculate active cell to place the chart
    Set rgCht = wsGr.Cells(i * 17 + 2, 2)

    Set cht = wsGr.ChartObjects.Add( _
            Left:=rgCht.Left, _
            Width:=rgCht.Width * 9, _
            Top:=rgCht.Top, _
            Height:=rgCht.Height * 16)
```

The result is that if the sheet is displayed on my notebook screen while the macro runs, all charts are placed and sized properly. However when I run it on a bigger screen, the charts are shifted 1 unit per row down, i. e. in line 70 I have 7 units difference between the calculated position and the real position on the sheet:

[image: results on different screens]

The line height is 14.5 units, so in row 70 the top position is 1000.5 . However when I manually move the chart to the top left corner of the cell and check the coordinates, I get 993.5.

I'm running out of ideas. Any hint is appreciated.

Both monitors run with a resolution of 1920x1080. Only difference is that the scaling is 125% on the big screen and 150% on the small one.

Comment: What happens if you set both monitors to the same scale? I've seen some weird stuff using different applications when scaling the screen, this might be one of those cases.

Comment: What if you use `Cells(i,2).Top` and `Cells(i,2).Left` instead?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad is correct. You could post it as an answer. I'm sure it will work, I use that method all the time at work and has never had any issues from any of the colleagues

Comment: @Andreas: changing the reference did not work. See my answer below.

Comment: I too am looking for a solution to this. The closest I've come is the very helpful post here, which may help. https://wellsr.com/vba/2019/excel/calculate-screen-size-and-other-display-details-with-vba/